# gcc 10.1: weird behavior with clang-tidy (clion) and precompiled headers (cmake)

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clang, clion

I have had problems with my IDE since an update to GCC 10.1 a few days ago. I use CLion, which uses clang-tidy as linter. I also use the newly introduced command [target_precompiled_headers](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_precompile_headers.html) from CMake to use PCH for my project. Unfortunately I get weird linter warning and error messages:

[image: pic1][image: pic2]

That's how I include the header file for my pch in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_precompile_headers(Peach PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Src/peach_pch.h)
```

Strangely enough, my program compiles perfectly. So the error messages must (obviously) be wrong. This is very irritating for me and my development process. With GCC 9 I did not have these problems. Unfortunately I have no possibility to downgrade at the moment. Also with Clang 10 the same problem occurs. Without PCH the error messages do not appear. But I do not want to work without it.

I've already done a lot of research. There is an open bug for clang: [bugs.llvm.org](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21174#c11).
But I really don't know whether this is the problem or something else. It is hard to find out if the error is in CLion, GCC, Clang or something else. I only observed that with GCC 10.1 the error occurred for the first time.

Maybe someone has an idea or at least the same issue.

**EDIT:**

I kinda solved the issue by myself. I used the C++20 standard within my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

When I switch to C++17 the "error" messages disappeared. I had the guess, that there are some overlaps in the std lib since `std::ranges` (the error from the picture) exists since C++20.

So I think it could be a bug in the latest version of GCC?

Comment: The error message suggests this code is already within the namespace `std::ranges`, does this mean anything to you? Do you have this namespace in a `using` statement somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. But I have absolutly no idea where it comes from. I never use the `using` statement

Comment: It's a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-20238) in CLion. About std::string [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-19877)

Comment: @MaximBanaev I don't think the bug describes the same issue (see pictures)

Comment: I don't see the difference, sorry. The problem is not introduced by using precompiled header. It can be simply reproduced with [example](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-20238#focus=streamItem-27-4134034.0-0). The initial problem with clangd which CLion is using as C++ language engine. I bet if you disable it in *Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | C/C++ | Clangd* the problem is gone.