# why are all my std namespaces broken after updating msys gcc from 9.2 to 10.1.0

Tags: clion, c++20, msys2

I just updated my msys gcc compiler from 9.2.0 to 10.1.0. Afterwards all functions inside std:: namespace cannot be found and are now behind namespace ::std:: with leading double colon and all Gtest MACROS e.g TEST are highlighted as errors. here's an example:

std::in_place without leading double colon gives an error : no member named "in_place" in namespace 'std::ranges::std'

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941032/gcc-10-1-weird-behavior-with-clang-tidy-clion-and-precompiled-headers-cmake

Comment: Thanks god I'm not the only one. I hope it gonna get fixed quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-20238) with CLion 2020.1.x. The current W/A is to use C++17 until they will fix it and provide bugfix update.

Comment: am glad this issue is not a gcc related issue. thanks for the response.